# Strange Heroku CLI errors / warnings - 'already initialized constant'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I keep getting the following errors every time I run any heroku command from the command line.  Any ideas why?  I couldn't find anything on this.

Users/monkey/.heroku/plugins/heroku-pg-extras/lib/heroku/client/heroku_postgresql_backups.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Version

/Users/monkey/.heroku/plugins/heroku-pg-extras/lib/heroku/command/pg_backups.rb:62: warning: already initialized constant MaybeAttachment

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update your plugins with 'heroku plugins:update'

Your pgbackups one is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to only occur when Heroku is running pg auto-backups on the database. I simply waited for awhile and tried to run some heroku commands again and got no errors. I checked the time and it correlates to the time backups were scheduled to run on heroku.